# /sys on the host is becoming read-only once Docker is started

Tags: docker

/sys on the host is becoming read-only once Docker is started. /sys is only read-only after the first docker container has been launched. You can remount /sys back writeable, but it only lasts until another container is started.

```
[root@srpafapp0113 ~]# docker version
Client version: 1.7.1
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 786b29d/1.7.1
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.7.1
Server API version: 1.19
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 786b29d/1.7.1
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
[root@srpafapp0113 ~]#

[root@srpafapp0113 ~]# docker info
Containers: 3
Images: 64
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-253:6-14-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 4.244 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 14.69 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 5.095 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.142 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Data loop file: /opt/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata loop file: /opt/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.117-RHEL6 (2016-08-15)
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 2.6.32-642.6.2.el6.x86_64
Operating System: <unknown>
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.68 GiB
Name: servertst0113
ID: F7QY:GBET:D3SX:ADNJ:5LKF:FVXS:U3MJ:QLVD:7C3R:ZDFN:ENTW:MNBV
```

The OS version: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago)

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

the version of docker you are running is very old, it is dated July 2015 (https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#171-2015-07-14) and I see several items in the Docker's changelog about /sys file system.

My advice would be to upgrade to the latest version of docker that most probably don't have such problems.

There are several articles around the web talking about this, all related to older versions of docker

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7101